# hide splashscreen after InAppBroswer has finished loading

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, splash-screen, inappbrowser

I am having trouble delaying the splashscreen on IOS and Android and only removing it when the InAppBroswer has finish. This is the logic I have tried

**config.xml**

```
<preference name="splashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example App</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Global InAppBrowser reference
var iabRef = null;


function onDeviceReady() {
iabRef = window.open('https://www.example.com/app', '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { 
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
}, false );
}
</script>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/app" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
</body>
</html>
```

The splashscreen shows for a split second, then a whitescreen for about 5 seconds.

The logic in the index was to hide the splashscreen after inAppBroswer has finish loading(**loadstop**) but this doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas please.

**console.log(navigator)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inappbrowser has a callback after page is finish loading.

Read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). See [addEventListener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#addeventlistener)

It might look like this:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});
```

Comment: is navigator.splashscreen.hide(); meant to return true or false? do you have any idea because at the moment when i try to alert or console log it. I get undefined please have a look at on the question what console.log(navigator) shows for `splashscreen`

Comment: `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` returns neither true or false, if anything it would return `'undefined'` - which is falsy. This article will help [Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: thanks that article just remind me why I don't like javascript very much. Why brings me to question at hand. if `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` returns neither true or false then how do you know its working or not.

Comment: `falsey == false` and `false === false`. Also `if (falsey) {nothinghappens(); } else {thishappens();}` and `if (false === false) { nothinghappens() } else { thishappens(); }` In summary, when you compare with `===` then it compares object-type and boolean comparison; such that both must be satisfied. --- The confusion you are having is likely because you are thinking about compile language and strict type-ing. (type is a noun) JavaScript is interpreted and loosely typed. (again type is a noun).

Comment: OOPs THAT WAS WRONG. THIS IS CORRECT: if (false === false) { THIShappens(); } else { nothinghappens(); }

Answer (score -1):

They seem to be a bug to do with splashscreen in the lastest update, It seems that you can't set `AutoHideSplashScreen` to `false` and then using `SplashScreenDelay` at the same time

But

seem to work fine and because that works `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` works also I think